# ActiveAdmin pagination links are gone with scoped_collection group by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, activeadmin

I have the following ActiveAdmin model:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Job do

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      Job.all
    end
  end
```

This works just fine, the pagination and the links. However, I need to use a more complex query to list the count of Job views for each job. So I changed my scoped collection to this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Job do

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      Job.joins('left join jobView on job.Id = jobView.JobId')
            .select('job.Id, job.Title, job.CreatedDate, job.DeadLineDate, 
                 job.IsClosed, job.IsPublic, job.IsApproved, count(1) as totalViews')
            .group('job.Id, job.Title, job.CreatedDate, job.DeadLineDate, 
                 job.IsClosed, job.IsPublic, job.IsApproved')
    end
  end
```

The second works. But the pagination links are not showing anymore. I can even see that the pagination itself works, because if I insert in the browser a query string like '?page=2' it paginates correctly to page 2. The only real problem is the missing links for changing pages on the bottom of the page.

Anyone knows what's going on? Thanks guys.

**EDIT**

I've found out that the problem happens because, if you do something like:

```
model = MyModel.select(field1, field2) 
model.count
```

model.count will break because rails is executing a query like

```
select count(field1, field2) from MyModel
```

However, `count` just accepts 1 parameter. And ActiveAdmin paginations probably does a `count`.

The solution would be to use `size` instead count. But how to change this behavior in AA?

**Edit 2 - Found ugly solution**

Since I use a left join in my query, the number of rows  will always be equal to the left table count. So, I did a count on my Job table inside my Index Controller and then I passed this count to a partial where I build the pagination links by myself:

/admin/job.rb:

```
 index do
    ...

    @jobsForPagination = Job.all.page(params[:page]).per(8) 
    render partial: "paginate", locals: {resource: @jobsForPagination}
  end
```

/views/admin/jobs/_paginate.html.erb:

```
<%= paginate resource %>
```

8 is the activeadmin config.per_page.

If someone finds a better solution or has any comments, please reply.

Thank you!

Comment: You can try this `super.joins ...`

Comment: thks @TimoSchilling, but the problem remains..

Comment: ok, but you should use `super` otherwise you lost the auth stuff for example

Comment: Thanks @TimoSchilling. I'm using super now.